# Error al abrir la conexion Oracle en el servidor ORA-3134

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en ASP.NET la cual al momento de publicar la aplicacion y posteriormente querer iniciar sesion realiza una conexion a la base de datos de oracle (Oracle 9i) me manda un mensaje de error el cual  dice lo siguiente:
**Tengo instalado en el servidor ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20)**
Es el mismo cliente que tengo en mi computadora local y donde se conecta sin problemas.

```
ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION ORA-3134: CONNECTIONS TO THIS 
SERVER VERSION ARE NO LONGER SUPPORTED.    AT 
ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION.HANDLEERRORHELPER(INT32 ERRCODE, 
ORACLECONNECTION CONN, INTPTR OPSERRCTX, OPOSQLVALCTX* POPOSQLVALCTX, 
OBJECT SRC, STRING PROCEDURE, BOOLEAN BCHECK)
AT ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION.HANDLEERROR(INT32 ERRCODE, 
ORACLECONNECTION CONN, INTPTR OPSERRCTX, OBJECT SRC)
AT ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLECONNECTION.OPEN()
```

Cabe aclarar que al momento de correrlo localmente en mi computadora lo hace sin problemas.

lo cual se me hace extraño por que cree una aplicacion en consola que hace la conexion a la misma base de datos y si corre sin problemas en el servidor donde estoy publicando el proyecto y si me trae registros.
Me podrian ayudar en solucionar este problema.
Esta es la DLL que utilizo tanto para la que realice en consola como para el proyecto web. Incluso estoy utilizando el mismo metodo en las dos aplicaciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos.

Comment: El driver the oracle del servidor es de una versión superior a la de base de datos. Verifica que version del Oracle dataacess tienes en tu computador y cual es la del servidor. Deben ser diferentes te aseguro

Comment: La aplicación de consola utiliza exactamente la misma forma de conexión al servidor de BD? En ASP.NET es un poco diferente.

Comment: asi es @JuanCarlosGuibovich uso exactamente la misma forma en que lo llamo yla misma dll de oracle dataacces

Comment: Estas publicando en IIS supongo y tienes un web.config con un connectionstring? Podria ver el connectionstring si lo anterior es cierto?

Comment: cLARO @JuanCarlosGuibovich esta es mi cadena de conexion: <add key="CONEXION_ORACLE_ADQUIS" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.XX.XXX.X)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mty)));User Id = adquis; Password = XXXXXX;"/>

Comment: La verdad nunca habia visto ese formato de conexión y al parecer estas dependiendo del oracle cliente configurado al IIS o al equipo. Mis conexiones por si te ayuda en algo son:  <add name="MI_CONEXION" connectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=TSNNAME;Persist Security Info=True;Password=xxxx;User ID=USER" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" /> Aqui indico que utilizo el System.Data.OleDb con Oracle y el Datasouse TSNAME es el nombre de la base de datos en tnsnames.ora que tiene el formato igual al tuyo.

Comment: Que librería estás utilizando para comunicarte con Oracle? Según tengo entendido, la librería que no requiere que el cliente de Oracle esté instalado ni configurado en la pc donde se estará ejecutado el sistema es la de Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Comment: hola @MaxParedes estoy utilizando la DLL de Oracle.DataAccess V 2.112.3.0 el cliente tengo instalado el cliente Oracle 11.2, corriendolo en mi computadora , si funciona sin problemas incluso cree una app de escritorio en el servidor donde estoy publicando el proyecto si me trae registros y estoy utilizando la misma dll que en el proyecto web.