# Problema al reemplazar una referencia en Visual Studio-ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.NET cuando inicie el proyecto agregue una referencia de Oracle.DataAccess la versión 2.112.3.0 hasta ahí todo bien , el problema es cuando por intento reemplazar esa dll por otra versión la 2.112.4.0 , por mas que le doy en quitar referencia y agregar la nueva me sigue agregando la primera que agregue con la misma ruta y todo la misma versión , me podrían ayudar en como removerla adecuadamente, la única manera de reemplazar la versión es cambiarla directamente en la carpeta bin cuando ya publico la aplicación.
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al abrir la conexion Oracle en el servidor ORA-3134](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320518/error-al-abrir-la-conexion-oracle-en-el-servidor-ora-3134)

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que editar directamente el csproj cambiandole la ruta , no quedo ota manera.
los pasos a seguir fueron:
1-Clic derecho en el proyecto --> Descargar proyecto 
2- Editar la ruta y la versión.